# Metro Get Dropped Data from Drop event

Tags: c#, listview, drag-and-drop, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a `Control`, on which I drag items from one of several other `Controls` (all `ListViewItems`).

The `Control` correctly raises the `Drop` event, as I have set all the appropriate properties.

Now, how do I get the `ListViewItems` that were dragged onto the control? I see a `Data` property, which may be useful - but I haven't a clue on how to use it to get the required info.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

Subscribe to `Drop` event. And access the data through `e.Data.GetView()` method.